# Collection of mathematical formulas

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, mathematics

What is the correct term for a collection of mathematical formulas in the form of a (small) handbook? I'm looking for a translation of the German noun “Formelsammlung”.

[Several](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?search=formelsammlung) [dictionarys](http://de.pons.eu/dict/search/results/?q=formelsammlung&l=deen) suggest the word “**formulary**”, but [the disambiguation page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formulary) does not indicate a meaning of this kind. [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/formulary) does support this meaning, but only as one among several. It appears that a pharmaceutical meaning is more common than a mathematical one. So I suppose that I should disambiuate the term. But I'm unsure whether to choose “**mathematical formulary**” or “**mathematics formulary**”. Or perhaps something completely different, like “**mathematical handbook**”.

Which term is most common or best suited to describe this kind of book?

Comment: I'd vote for *Handbook.*  [CRC](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=CRC+Handbook) is probably the most recognized for handbooks in my field.  But interestingly they don't call their "handbook" of mathematics a handbook, they just call it "CRC Standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae"

Comment: @Jim, perhaps you want to make that comment an answer, so that others who agree can vote as well.

Comment: @Jim, mine (27th ed, 1984) is titled simple "CRC Standard Mathematical Tables"

Comment: Tangentially, in engineering we have *databooks*, such as Calvert and Farrar's, which actually contain a lot of formulae (as well as data).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter how you research it, you will find that a frequently used title for a collection of mathematical formulas* includes the word **Handbook**: e.g., **Handbook of Mathematical Formulas** or **Handbook of Mathematical Functions** or something similar.

**Pocket Book** (or **pocketbook**) is sometimes used in place of "handbook" to suggest that the material is easy to keep close at hand.

Other words that work are **compendium** and **collection**. You will almost never find these in the title of the book, but you will often find it in the description of the book.

A search on Amazon.com (books) for the subject "mathematical formulas" shows that "handbook" is often part of the title, and where it is not, then simply stating something like "Mathematical Formulas" in the title is sufficient. E.g., "CRC Standard Mathematical Tables and Formulae".

*(By the way, and off-topic, "formulae" and "formulas" are used interchangeably.)

Answer (score 1):

Going by [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=mathematics%20formulary&aq=f&tbm=bks), it is recognised and acceptable to use *formulary* to refer to a collection of mathematical formulae. There is also a 1963 book titled, *Mathematical Formulary, Including All Formulae Required for Mathematics I and II*.

The [etymonline entry for formulary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=formula) notes:

> Mathematical use is from 1796; use in chemistry is from c.1846.

So, you are on safe ground etymologically as well.

Comment: How well do they sell? I'd go with 'Handbook of Mathematical Formulas'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The formula for that is, presumably, within :)

Comment: You haven't got one either?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth haha! That makes three of us :D

Answer (score -2):

The problem with using *formulary* for a collection of mathematical formulae is that a *formulary* already means a bunch of prescriptions, like your health insurance company’s formulary.

Since this is a technical sense, it may be better to return to the original Latin form, which would be a ***formularium***.  Of the *-arium* suffix, the OED writes:

> **-arium**, suffix of sbs. ad. L. *-ārium* ‘thing connected with or employed in, place for,’ orig. neuter of adjs. in -*ārius*. Of this the regular adapted form in Eng. is -*ary*: see -*ary*1, but the unchanged L. form is used with a few terms of classical and ecclesiastical antiquities, or of learned use, as *caldarium, frigidarium, sacrarium, honorarium, herbarium,* the last of which, being in general use, has probably popularized the use of *vivarium* and *aquarium*.

Other words of that ilk include the easily recognized. . .

- *antiquarium* for antiquities
- *cinerarium* for ashes (note that *cinerary* was already taken)
- *formicarium* for ants (*formicary* means the same thing)
- *leprosarium* for lepers
- *muscarium* for flies
- *ossuarium* for bones (*ossuary* means the same thing)
- *ranarium* for frogs
- *rosarium* for roses (note that *rosary* was already taken)
- *sanitarium* for health  (note that *sanitary* was already taken)
- *unguentarium* for ointment
- *vestiarium* for garments (the rare *vestiary* means the same thing, but so too does *vestry*)
- *viridarium* for greenery

When J. R. R. Tolkien needed a word for the collection of legends he was building up, he chose [*legendarium*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolkien%27s_legendarium).  Yes, it is fancier than the normal *-ary* suffix that would yield *legendary*, but that word was already taken.

In the same way, since a *formulary* is already taken, you might choose a *formularium* instead.

Comment: You make a strong point why “formularium” should be a suitable term, but I'm unsure how *established* it actually is. Would native speakers without a strong linguistic background choose that word as well? More likely than “mathematical formulary” and my other alternatives?

Comment: @MvG You’ll have to ask one of those kinds of people, as I am not one such. :) But for me, a “mathematical formulary” would be something having to do with pharmaceuticals, albeit perhaps numerically, because I am too poisoned with the health-care sense.